# How do I bind an expression to <paper-button>.active?

Tags: polymer

I'd like to activate a `<paper-button>` using an expression bound to its `active` property, but this code doesn't work:

```
<paper-button id="btnPointDown" on-click="{{decrement}}" active="{{points == 0}}">\/</button>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that `on-click="{{decrement}}"` should be `on-click="decrement"`. [Event listener annotations](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#annotated-listeners) take only the method name as a value (without brackets).

Answer (score 0):

In Polymer, you can't put an expression directly in the bindings. You have to use a function, which will return your condition result, and use it in the binding instead.

With your example, it would look something like this:

```
<paper-button id="btnPointDown" on-click="decrement" active="[[_checkIfPointsIsZero(points)]]">\/</paper-button>
```

The function `_checkIfPointsIsZero` will be evaluated each time `points` changes, assuming `points` is in the component's properties.

I also recommend using a simple data binding in that case.